# Совместное использование container и container-fluid в Bootstrap 3.5

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Допускается ли совместное использование классов `container-fluid` и `container`?
Можно ли их вкладывать друг в друга?

> Bootstrap 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно. Но зачем?

`container` - это базовый блок с фиксированной шириной контента с внутренними отступами по бокам для внутренних колонок.

`container-fluid` - это базовый блок со 100% шириной контента с внутренними отступами по бокам для внутренних колонок.

Они одинаковые по свойствам  только первому ширина задана, а второму нет. Он тянется во всю ширину по умолчанию, т.к. он блочный.

1 - Если одному диву вы зададите оба этих класса, то он станет дивом с фиксированной шириной. То есть добавится св-во от первого класса и смысла добавлять второй просто нет. То есть `container-fluid` превратится в `container`.

2 - если вовнутрь `container-fluid` поставить `container` - то все будет хорошо, до тех пор пока вы смотрите страницу на широком экране. При уменьшении страницы в размерах близких к [breakpoints](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) отступы одного контейнера будут внахлест на другой, контент съедет вправо, и не будет помещаться в экран.

3 - наоборот сделать можно почти без последствий, появится только дополнительный отступ справа и слева. Получается в блоке с фиксированной шириной находится блок с шириной занимающей все его пространство - нет проблем.

4 - ну и `container-fluid` во внутрь `container-fluid` аналогично без проблем - только появление дополнительных отступов.

Вот пример для наглядности(Смотрите на широком экране и уменьшайте окно браузера по ширине - смотрите за поведением)

```css
i{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
}
.b-c{
  color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
.b-c-f{
  color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.container{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
.container-fluid{
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <i><b class="b-c">container</b></i>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <i><b class="b-c-f">container-fluid</b></i>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="container">
    <i><b class="b-c">container</b> > <b class="b-c">container</b></i>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <i><b class="b-c">container</b> > <b class="b-c-f">container-fluid</b></i>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <i><b class="b-c-f">container-fluid</b> > <b class="b-c-f">container-fluid</b></i>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <i><b class="b-c-f">container-fluid</b> > <b class="b-c">container</b></i>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
```

---

Бутстрап предоставляет свою систему строения контента

> .container(-fluid)>.row>.col(-lg-*, -md-*,...)

И если вы пользуетесь бутсрапом, то пользуйтесь его сеткой. Для внутреннего разделения на горизонтальные блоки пользуйтесь `row`, вместо `container`.

Не нужно делать лишнего из блоков, которые для этого не предназначены.

**Изменив логику стандартного фреймворка вы усложняете в будущем обновление, отладку, и работу с таким проектом.**

Если у вас стоит какая-то сверх-задача пользуйтесь другим фреймворком, либо собственной версткой. Бутстрап - не панацея, далеко не идеален и не подходит для абсолютно всех задач.

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ!