# Комбинации вложенности классов Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

У меня вопрос касаемо того, какие классы Bootstrap, предназначенные для создания адаптивного макета, могут быть вложены друг в друга. Разумеется, число теоретически возможны любые комбинации, среди которых есть бессмысленные (к примеру, .row в .row).

Но если мы ориентируемся на создание адаптивного, отзывчивого (и далее по тексту) дизайна верны ли утверждения:

1) в .container / .container-fluid мы можем вложить .row и только .row ?

2) в .row мы можем вложить .col-X-X и только .col-X-X ?

3) в .col-X-X мы можем вложить и .container / .container-fluid и .row ?

4) .container / .container-fluid может быть вложен в любой класс, в любой тег, в том числе и в Bootstrap'овский .col-X-X ?

5) .row может быть вложен как и в .container / .container-fluid, так и в .col-X-X ?

6) .col-X-X может быть вложен как и в .row, так и .container / .container-fluid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0 - `.row` в `.row` можно вкладывать, и это не бессмысленно, только не на прямую. Это делается тогда, когда вы хотите поделить например `.col`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-6'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-2'>2</div>
        <div class='col-3'>3</div>
        <div class='col-7'>7</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

1,2 - да, это принцип основы сетки бутстрап

3 - нет, это бессмысленно, так как контейнер если он не fluid будет иметь свою ширину, и верстка поедет, а если он не резиновый, то это вообще смысла не имеет

4 - по сути да, но сетка бутсрапа сконструирована таким образом, что в `container` вы вкладываете `row`, а затем `col`

5, 6 - см п 0. Нужно понимать, для чего они существуют, для наглядности можете посмотреть похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/661868/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-container-%D0%B8-container-fluid-%D0%B2-bootstrap-3-5/662987#662987). Контейнер должен быть в роли основного контейнера, а для тогд чтобы были отступы не заходящие за борт - нужны row и col.

Читайте [документацию](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/), там все подробно описано с примерами.

В этом смысле, построения базовой сетки бутстрап 3 от 4 не отличается. Да они переписали их на флексбоксах, но смысл тот же.

Comment: Большое спасибо за развёрнутый ответ.
4. А может быть колонка непосредственным родителем для контейнера?

И вообще в большинстве случаев приходится в контейнер, ряд или колонку вкладывать контейнер (я имею в виду непосредственно,не через несколько уровней)?

Comment: Вы можете сделать как хотите, другой вопрос, зачем это нужно, оправдано ли это и т.д. В любом случае, чтобы пользоваться классами не по правилам описанным в документации, нужно хорошо понимать как они работают, чтобы не было сюрпризов.